# Ubuntu Failed to install and now I don't know which partition it's on so I don't have access to my other 500GB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-10

I tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my Windows 10 system as a dual boot. It got all the way to the end and told me that the drive was unclean (Can't remember exact warning); Research told me that something with the safe boot could have messed it up but I found out that I can achieve what I needed with a Linux subsystem. Now the failed Ubuntu install is holding my other 500 GB hostage because it had partitioned my drive before failing. Since windows is installed on my SSD, would I have to worry about vital stuff getting deleted if I just delete the partition that says "EFI System" since Ubuntu uses EFI?

How can I figure out which partition it took so I can delete it and gain back that space? I worry about deleting a vital partition and completely screwing my computer up. I have two drives, one is a 128GB SSD and the other is a 1TB HDD, it seems to have partitioned my HDD but I don't know if it installed its self on my SSD too, either way I just need the space back. I should have paid more attention but I've never had a problem when doing this before so I just blew through the installation...I've learned my lesson. Can anyone give me some advice?

Extra Info: I can boot into Ubuntu but it just takes me to a command line. If I enter 'exit' it takes me to a MOK screen where I can supposedly register keys and such. When I exit the MOK screen it defaults to windows because there isn't anything to boot into. Would I be able to get some sort of identifying information from the command line that could help? The names of the partitions are the exact same except on says "Healthy (EFI System)"

Partition image with windows
[image: Partition image with windows]

Ubuntu/Grub command line
[image: Ubuntu/Grub command line]

Comment: It sounds like you already know more than I do, but if you boot from a live CD or USB device, you should be able to use GParted to find out which disk it took.

Comment: Post a image of your partitions. You can do this by any partition manager (Windows disk management or Gparted in Ubuntu). Also post the outputs of `sudo parted -l` and `sudo fdisk -l` from the cmdline.

Comment: Don’t touch the EFI partition. It’s usually part of the Windows boot process. It may be that your HDD is developing hardware problems

Comment: Good suggestion @StephenDaddona I'll check that out today.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha from the windows cmdline or the failed ubuntu cmd line?

Comment: @PonJar I got it literally five days ago, it's not a hardware issue. **There are two EFI partitions**, one on the SSD where windows is and one on the HDD. It's just that Ubuntu took a partition and now i have no idea which one it is. I know nothing is wrong with the hardware because before trying to install Ubuntu on dual boot, the HDD said it had 1000GB open and ready to go.

Comment: @SilverStrings024 The ubuntu cmdline. Also post the images from windows disk manager (right click on start button and select disk management), Gparted from ubuntu USB and if you have one, a 3rd party partition manager in windows like easeus.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I modified the question to include the screenshots. Sorry for the poor quality at the command line for ubuntu but I had no other way to take a picture of it but my phone. When I entered 'exit' it tried to boot into windows and for some reason it popped up saying "Scanning and Repairing Drive (C:)" So now I'm worried about trying to boot into it again :/ It says it's the GNU Grub command line so.....yeah

Comment: @SilverStrings024 That is the grub cmdline. To exit that and proceed to ubuntu type `normal` and press enter. If that doesn't get you to Ubuntu, type `normal` press enter and press the `esc` key continuously until the grub menu appears and select ubuntu from there.

Comment: Hey why was my answer deleted?

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I'm not sure why your first answer was deleted. But I'm curious why you issued a 100 point bounty? I don't think you can award it to your second answer.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha Thank you, I'll try that. No idea why your answer was deleted, this is the first time I've been on here since I last posted.

Comment: Windows does not show Linux partitions. Better to have all the details, rather than guess (guess' may be correct as near as I can tell). May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  Acer often needs "trust" settings to work.

Comment: @SasukeUchiha I haven't accepted any answers, I've been really busy and can't just monitor this post all the time. I get you're trying to help but realize that I have no idea what I'm doing here and I worry about destroying my pc. I don't see it as unfair considering I haven't accepted anything nor have I even been on this post for days. If I were to have known you bounties it I may have came back sooner but I didn't, so I didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disk 1 partition 3** is the partition that according to you, *Ubuntu is holding hostage*. You can safely delete this and get the space back. But as you have the `EFI system partition` in the middle, you will have trouble combining it with the `D:` partition. There are workarounds. For example, you can do this with the Easeus Partition Master Paid version. You can find a safe crack if you try. ([I found a safe one from YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YEAIDkzLIZY).) You can also delete the `EFI system partition` (after finding whether it is safe to do so with [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us) and/or [Microsoft Community Advocates](https://partner.support.services.microsoft.com/en-gb/contact/chat/19/?mode=live&rejoinToken=jLfYpey5rcJBPIxTHK%2BWdOl89gFXGiC5Tq%2B8Uo1EzXl510Nf6js2b8AwUK31a%2B4jEJ7GFzzB4yvzOJjJYealFDrXYrsAA30zVF1Oka9w%2F0y%2BZfOJcfiHARSk59E8iWmMaafXrTr2Amiyv80rQd9BcPkfR12nGvYmt5vnk0kLFYAGzHMhzbLKCKyDKPt8hd%2FWqEQ7FTGW2ovLWyWzrwJ9BrGiwJJQfnSlCM5ASOML1oGxnlix5s%2FWVVmyURsfp0yGoM%2F%2Fxlbz3q%2B1trGgUA4tmQTYlLVmVQv3XjJt8lYtnVoTpVLbU1T7vVKmGd0gHGBAm%2BHEX%2BFVyaikQzskJj%2F1JQ5TSfV5fdnzNO50tzSSpJutuJHMSxFljCZtoZL826dSsu9xEYdRss5W6e2yz5sJ4JMqH0C7Ay1G2e7o7OAmwwaqDYtd6iZOMgehhJOCCN8m2YJySPA4Yy9gjZCz0Cd%2F6g%3D%3D&uuid=942d0346-2bf6-4499-9f94-2ffe6f11dd8d).) and combine the partition with `D:`. Another way to use that space is to assign a new drive letter like `E:` and use it as a separate partition.

Comment: When I deleted disk 1 partition 3 it told me that it was used by another operating system so you were correct. I deleted the volume but now I can't merge it because it says that there isn't enough space on the drive. I'm accepting the answer because it did indeed technically give me back my space. Since I still need Linux, I'm going to attempt to reinstall Ubuntu but my live USB keeps getting stuck on install select (minimum or full version) or during install. I turned safe boot off in BIOS and don't see a fast boot option so hopefully it will work now but...we'll see...

Comment: @SilverStrings024 I will try to help you out further if you want. Sorry if I sounded a bit aggressive. How did it go? By stuck do you mean it exits the procedure or just prevent you from doing anything? Also, fast boot is in control pannel. Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\System Settings. Click change options that are currently unavailable and turn it off. Also make sure you didn't hibernate.

Comment: You did but it's cool, reputation means alot on here and it would suck to lose that much. I just haven't been able to get on here for a while and didn't know you bountied it. The partition is deleted and I'm currently using rufus to redo the live USB with the 20.04 ISO, Not sure why it kept freezing when trying to get through the install but I'm gonna try it again and see if it will work now. I just don't understand the freezing and I don't have an optical drive to use a DVD nor an external drive to make a portable linux system :/

Comment: Any improvement?

Comment: No, it's still taking forever to move on from the install selection screen (where you select normal install, minimal install, install third party software) I keep installing the third party software because I have an NVIDIA GPU that I need to use for AI and the toolkit doesn't let windows use it. Should I try it without internet, a minimal install, and no third party software?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem as you have secure boot disabled and have plenty of space. But I guess you could try. I don't think it will have much of an effect though. Also did you turn fast startup off?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108386/discussion-between-sasuke-uchiha-and-silverstrings024).

Comment: I am indeed able to chat, sent one! @SasukeUchiha

Comment: Does try ubuntu option work?

Answer (score 1):

On base of screenshot you posted, I would suggest to leave **Disk (D:) (1st Partition from Left side)** and delete remaining two partitions EFI one (middle) and another with 464.62 GB (right one) on **Disk 1**.

Comment: I agree and would do exactly this if I was in this situation. Don't touch anything on disk0. There is a tiny chance that the Ubuntu install reconfigured you to boot Windows through the 513mb EFI partition and that removing it will prevent windows from booting. If you want to be super safe, you can test first by shutting down, unplugging the hdd (disk1) and making sure you can still boot windows. If so, plug it back it and delete away. (Of course, if there is any critical data on there, there's no substitute for a proper backup.)

Answer (score 0):

After Going to Ubuntu Grub terminal
Type **ls**
it displays all the current partitions on your pc similar to **(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos3)** depending on your partitions.
Then for each partition like msdos1 type **ls (hd0,msdos1)** or for msdos2 type **ls (hd0,msdos2)** for all the partitions, if for any partitions you get message "FileSystem is ext2 "or "FileSystem is ext3" then this is ur required partition but if for all such partition you get "FileSystem is unknown"  then type **set** and it displays your required information like cmdpath = (hd0) ,prefix = (hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub ,root = (hd0,msdos7)

so after the above steps, you find your partition and to recover from its type in the terminal

if for example, you find that msdos6 is your required partition then type

**set boot=(hd0,msdos6)**

**set prefix=(hd0,msdos6)/boot/grub**

**insmod normal**

**normal**

your pc boots and your fine to switch between the Windows and Linux

Comment: When typing in ls it shows... (proc), (hd0), (hd1), (hd1,gpt4), (hd1,gpt3), (hd1,gpt2),(hd1,gpt1), (hd2), (hd2, gpt3), (hd2, gpt2), (hd2, gpt1) when typing ls (hd0,msdos1) it shows "Filesystem type *ext - modification time" then it lists the time and for every one (no matter the input, i.e (hd1,msdos1) (h2,msdos7) ) it shows the same UUID and total size.

Comment: Since your partition shows hd1,gpt1 and so on then instead of ls ( hd0,msdos1 ) type the partitions ls (hd1,gpt1) and all other similar partition and then follow as stated since you have gpt  instead of msdos based partitions

Comment: Sasuke Uchiha was right, I got the space back. But do you think the partitions being gpt based could be why my attempts to install ubuntu are failing? The farthest I've gotten so far is installing the system. Then the installer freezes

Comment: Can you tell what output did you get when you executed for example  ls (hd1,gpt1) for such partitions??

Comment: The exact same thing as putting in ls (hd1,gpt1) it shows the same drive with *ext as the format

Comment: Have you execute for all partitions and tell whether all of them show the same output???

Comment: yes, I did the same thing for all of them and they all yielded the same results

Comment: If that's issue , then type set and check the cmdpath and prefix and boot and do as given above use gpt instead of msdos

Comment: Thanks, but I'm having a new problem, got to installation on ubuntu and now windows thinks that the ubuntu partition is part of the windows file system. I have to go through some hoops to try to fix it but at this point it may be easier to reinstall windows and start from scratch